# Firebase storage/retry-limit-exceeded error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, electron, firebase-storage

I have problem with my app. It's based on electron + react boilerplate. I tried to link Firebase Storage to let user download files, but I can't make it work.

Everytime when I try to make any operation on the storage (list files, getDownloadURL, download file, upload file) I get error:

> Firebase.tsx:31 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded)

So far my code looks like this for debug:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL} from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain: ...
  projectId: ...
  storageBucket: ...
  messagingSenderId:...
  appId:...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = getStorage(app);

const file = ref(storage, '/maps/122.png');

async function getURL() {
  let data = await getDownloadURL(file);
  console.log(data);
}

function Firebase() {
  return <button onClick={() => getURL()}>Click</button>;
}
```

After I click on the button I wait for about few seconds and this error shows in console.

- Tried different functions
- Tried different arguments
- Read docs and copy paste the original code
- Tried to change rules for allow all
- Check the retry limit value and it's default

Comment: same thing here. You solved it somehow?

Comment: @adammo unfortunetly not, I just switch to PocketBase

Comment: Just letting you know I reached out to firebase team and they responded that uploadString is limited by header size that can be pushed to their servers (8/16KB iirc)

Comment: @adammo: did you end up using another function to upload the file then? Either way, it'd be useful if you could share the info and your solution in an answer below - so that others are more likely to find it.